# Change user password in an active directory machine located in another domain

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

I have this code to change the password of a user in an active directory:

```
 DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://0.0.0.0/CN=John Smith,OU=12345,OU=Project,DC=mysite,DC=local");

 directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
 directoryEntry.Username = "adminusername";
 directoryEntry.Password = "adminpassword";

 directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "newPassword" });
 directoryEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account
```

When I try to execute this code directly into the server where is located the active directly, this work perfectly but when I try to execute it with a machine located in another domain, I receive this error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the ta
rget of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The RPC
 server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
```

This is the only one limitation that I have because with the same admin user and other credentials, I'm able to add user, remove user, add group, rename any object, etc... BUT not changing password.

Not that I tried with this code and it doesn't work too:

```
  public bool SetPassword(string userName, string newPassword, Domain.ActiveDirectory.Credentials credentials)
  {
     try
     {
        using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, credentials.ServerName, credentials.OrganizationalUnitsDn + "," + credentials.DomainControllerName))
        {
           using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
           {
              if (user == null)
              {
                 return false;
              }

              user.SetPassword(newPassword);

              return true;
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: How can you reset the password of a user which is on different domain? You must have either Credentials with admin rights of the same domain or you could have some sort of trust between two domains.

Comment: Who does the Provisioning for that particular AD Domain..? this should be done by an Admin.

Comment: Hi DJ Kraze, just to be sure that this is not the problem, I give to the user all rights.

Comment: @Samuel I have the same problem did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, I did'nt found any solution to this problem. In my case, that was for helping me in integration tests and I abandoned the change of passwords to replace it with a mock.